# Can I configure my Negear WGR614v7 to treat DCHP traffic like a hub?

Tags: routing, dhcp, switch, netgear, hub

I have a Negear WGR614v7 wireless router (Hardware Version V7, Firmware Version V2.0.30_2.0.30NA.) I've configured a Windows Server box to act as a DHCP server (among other things.)  My DHCP server is unable to serve addresses to clients, and the clients just time out.  It looks like my Netgear router is not broadcasting DHCP requests to everything hooked up to it, which seems exactly like what a router should do. Is there any way to configure the Netgear to act like a hub for DHCP traffic? Does my question even make sense? Sorry if it is totally off base, I'm a pretty good software engineer and my network administrator skills aren't quite as developed.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: You're likely better served over at superuser.com.

Comment: Indeed. Server Fault is geared more toward professional administration, and we don't do a lot of consumer grade stuff here. At [Super User](http://superuser.com/) it's much more geared toward home settings. You can flag your own question and request that it be migrated there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1-minute search on google reveals [this Netgear KB article](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/965). If you scroll down to the "Potential Issues" section, it indicates that the WGR614v6 may not correctly relay DHCP information. The suggested workaround is to use static IPs on all wireless devices connected to the Netgear router.

From your question it seems this problem was not fixed in the WGR614v7. If so, you're out of luck and will need to find an alternative solution.